# Is it necessary to have image resources for different screen density?

Tags: android, memory, android-drawable, android-resources

When I started learning Android, the course that I took mentioned about screen densities in a very early stage.

And it encouraged me to generate image resources for HDPI, XDPI, XXDPI and XXXDPI.

Whenever I get an image from designer, it is a XXDPI image and I will generate other versions using a plugin of Android Studio.

Later I started to doubt if this is really necessary.
As far as I can observe, the **only benefit** of having different resources for different screen density, is that I can use `wrap_content` for `ImageView` and the image will keep the same size in different screen densities.
But this can be completely replaced by using a `dp` value for the `ImageView`.

On the other hand, I observed quite a number of drawbacks:

1. Since multiple images are included, APK size increase (not 100% sure, may someone confirm?)
2. This approach can sometimes increase memory usage, if you unnecessarily used a very high resolution image (e.g. a fullscreen background image). [See this post for example](https://redfin.engineering/reduce-your-android-memory-footprint-with-nodpi-assets-a0a147fdf033).
3. Extra effort of generating different images
4. It is a nightmare if you need to have different drawable resources for another product flavor

So I start to think that why not just put a high resolution image in `nodpi` folder and let Android scales down for you? I never observed any observable drop in image quality. Will this cause any memory issue in a device with lower screen density?

Comment: problem will be when android scale up for xxhdpi, it could get to a really big size (if your nodpi res is already high-res), and your device can't display the image

Comment: Why would that happen? The image should fit to my view bounds.

Comment: would be the problem with loading the bitmap into the texture (max 4096x4096 for my Nexus 5) . Your image resolution might exceed the max. resolution allowed when it's resized.

Comment: Don't quite understand what you mean, but, it seems can be solved if I include an XXXHDPI source in no-dpi folder?

Comment: IMO, If you use high-resolution images even for smaller screens, Though the image would fit well, that would add extra overhead for rendering such high-resolution images when you could add a low-resolution image so the android system would need less memory and CPU to render the small size image. and most devices with smaller screens would have very limited resources, so you would want to make the process as efficient as you can.